# How to make the subindex appear below the arrow?

Tags: arrows

I want to write a limit with the "arrows' notation." This is, instead of `\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n} = x` I want to use `x_{n} \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty} x`. My problem is that with this last code, the `n \rightarrow \infty` appears down to the right of the arrow, and I would like it to appear below the arrow. How can I do that?

Comment: BTW, you can us \to instead of \rightarrow (reads better).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the extensible arrow `\xrightarrow` provided by `amsmath`, which has two arguments, an optional one for text below the arrow and a mandatory one for text above the arrow

```
\xrightarrow[text below]{text above}
```

In your case you have to use

```
\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
x_{n} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} x
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in the limit it's better to use `\to` rather than `\rightarrow`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with the `amsmath` package's `\underset` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\xtend{-\!\!\!}
\begin{document}
\[ x_{n} \underset{\scriptscriptstyle n \rightarrow \infty}{\xtend\xtend\rightarrow} x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a way with a stack.  the option argument (here `[2pt]`) controls the depth of the underset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\xtend{-\!\!\!}
\begin{document}
\[ x_{n} \mathrel{%
  \stackunder[2pt]{\xtend\xtend\rightarrow}{\scriptscriptstyle n \rightarrow \infty}} x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\underset` sets the "limit" too far away from the main arrow.  this would be a disaster in an in-line expression.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree.  But being always joked with about doing everything via stacks, I thought I would show something using `amsmath` too.  I guess I should stick with stacks `8^b`

Comment: @barbarabeeton  I would add that the other given answer (`\xrightarrow`) also ruins linespacing.  Only the stacking approach (perhaps with a `0pt` underset) looks nice inline.

Comment: well, the main arrow would look better if it were a little longer.  at least the back-tip of the arrowhead shouldn't poke at the infinity.  (actually, if i were copyediting something that contained that expression in text, i would encourage the author to find some other way.)